# ACH Transaction Processing

Tags: payment-gateway

Is there any ACH payment gateway services available like credit card payment gateways where we get success/failure(insufficient fund/invalid account details) instantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Banks do not process in real time, so an overdraft would not be identified until after their processing cutoff. Even then, different banks have different policies; some may positive pay an overdraft if the account is not frozen or in the process of being closed. A decision might not be made until one or more business days afterwards, and the final decision is often made by a human. Since a draft is usually cross-cleared, (say the gateway uses Fifth Third, and the draft is on Wells Fargo) the gateway would not even know if the account details were correct. It is illegal to share that kind of information between banks.

Answer (score 1):

You could check out [Dwolla's ACH API](http://www.dwolla.com/ach/ach-api). As explained above, you can't get real-time status updates because an ACH transaction does not happen instantly. However, within the API, transfers are noted as either processed, pending, canceled, failed, or reclaimed. More on the [transfers endpoint in the developer documentation](https://docsv2.dwolla.com/#transfers).

Answer (score 0):

The nearest thing to real-time bank-account validation uses the PIN debit networks, and is often marketed as "check verification."  There is a payments gateway provider called Forte Payments that offers this service to merchants and API developers.  At one time their product was called "ATM Verify" and covered about 60% of checking accounts in the U.S.